# Need help converting the ajax and php for wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

From guides I have gotten this far:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'do_enqueue_scripts');

function do_enqueue_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script('Java', plugins_url( '/js/form.js', __FILE__ ),      array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    wp_localize_script( 'Java', 'start', array(
        'code' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_func', 'func');
add_action('wp_ajax_func', 'func');

function func() 
{
    $From = $_POST['dateTo'];
    $To = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    echo $From . " - " . $To . " - " . $Name;
    die();
}
```

```js
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: start.code, 
        type: "POST",       
        data: new FormData(this), 
        contentType: false,      
        cache: false,           
        processData:false,      
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

My problem comes in with the AJAX call. I am still getting used to this action system WordPress is using and I am not sure what I need to change my data to. I have a generic form with 2 dates and a name; nothing crazy. However the returned data to my AJAX call is zero.

I believe my issue now is how I m either returning data to my ajax or with the data type I am send to my PHP function `func()`.

No errors in chrome or mozilla consoles.

Comment: When you say the 'response is zero', do you mean there is no response, or that it's literally a string `0` character? Also, have you checked the request in the network tab of the console to see what the response code is?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Yes I mean return is 0. I also added an isset condition to ensure the 3 variables are setting. Return from success is still 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input field to your form with the name of the action so wp can execute the right function

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="func">
```

change your ajax to:

```
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: start.code, 
        type: "POST",       
        data: $(this).serialize(),   
        cache: false,           
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: Hi this didnt, change the result could you explain the reasoning behind this so I could see what else I am missing to make it work? ^^

Comment: you goth to tell wordpress what function to execute when you do the ajax without the action the ajax returns 0 see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: upload.js?ver=1.0:43 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stringify is not a function(…) , would making $(this).stringify90 into JSON.stringify(this) or JSON.stringify($(this)) not work ?

Comment: still 0 :(, what else should I be looking at? I alert the information we set as data and its being set. It also says action=func

Comment: Hi, I got it to work thank you sooo much enjoy the thumbs up and answer.